# Raphael dotchart display issue

Tags: raphael, graphael

I'm using the dot chart example code from http://g.raphaeljs.com/dotchart.html, 
however it doesn't work well if I vary the data. 
The usage is also similar, though the number of Y and X values may 
change.
I have external code that generates the proper number of  xs and ys values. 
I find that I have to change the height and width if I have more (or 
less) x/y labels/data.  I also have to adjust the width if one of the x/y 
labels.

How can I make height and width of DOT chart dynamic?
all helps are appreciated.